# SWIG: difference between %import and %include

Tags: c++, swig

The [SWIG docs](http://www.swig.org/Doc2.0/Preprocessor.html) explain these two directives as follows:

- `%include`: "To include another file into a SWIG interface, use the `%include` directive ... Unlike, `#include`, `%include` includes each file once (and will not reload the file on subsequent `%include` declarations). Therefore, it is not necessary to use include-guards in SWIG interfaces."
- `%import`: "SWIG provides another file inclusion directive with the `%import` directive ... The purpose of `%import` is to collect certain information from another SWIG interface file or a header file without actually generating any wrapper code. Such information generally includes type declarations (e.g., typedef) as well as C++ classes that might be used as base-classes for class declarations in the interface. "

My question is what are the differences between these two directives and what are the pros/cons of using each?

---

P.S. Just for some background info. I have a simple C++ - python extension that builds and works when I use either of the above directives. One, however (`%import`) gives fewer warnings when I call `swig -c++ -python my_file.i`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The way SWIG works is that it assumes that any valid C++ declarations you provide are to be exposed to the target language. Therefore, any C++ code that SWIG is provided will be used to generate an interface.

`%import` is an inclusion mechanism that *prevents* the generation of the interface for the code it includes. That's the difference. So the question you ask when including a header is, "Do I want all of the stuff in this header to be exposed to the target language?" If the answer is "no", then you use `%import`.