# How to ignore a class type wrapped in another library?

Tags: java, c++, cmake, swig

I am making a project with SWIG for binding C++ inside a java application I use Cmake to compile). I did a library containing a class named `Data`. I used SWIG to generate some Java code, and a file named `Data.java` was created. Then, I compiled all the java files into a .jar.

Now, I am trying to do an other project with Swig (still C++ to Java). This project has a class `Test` with a method taking a `Data` as argument, like this :

**Test.h**

```cpp
class Test
{
    public:
        void process(Data input);
};
```

When I launch SWIG with cmake, it generates a Java file named `SWIGTYPE_p_Data_t.java` (which is normal, because it doesn't know the class `Data`).

I am wondering if there is a way to tell SWIG to use the .jar I created for the first library (or at least a folder containing the .java files), so it will have the Java class `Data` and it will not create the Java class `SWIGTYPE_p_Data_t.java`.

Comment: Is this what you're looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30413268/168175

Comment: Yes, it seems to be that. I didn't know that it is possible to import an interface file. Thank you !