# SWIG wrapper of C++ library for Python - submodules

Tags: c++, python-3.x, g++, swig

I'm trying to wrap a C++ library into a Python3 interface using SWIG, and there is a problem I can't quite fix. This library has several namespaces, and I would like to make them modules of the library when wrapped in Python. Assume the following minimal example:

```
lib_class.hpp lib_class.cpp
lib_ops.hpp   lib_ops.cpp
io_ops.hpp    io_ops.cpp
```

The files `lib_class` define a very small class:

- `lib_class.hpp`

```
#pragma once
namespace lib {
class dummy {
    private:
        int a;
    public:
        dummy();
        dummy(int t_a);
        ~dummy();
        void asdf();
};
}
```

- `lib_class.cpp`

```
#include "lib_class.hpp"
namespace lib {
dummy::dummy() {}
dummy::dummy(int t_a) : a(t_a) {}
dummy::~dummy() {}
void dummy::asdf() { a = 3; }
}
```

The files `lib_ops.hpp` and `lib_ops.cpp` define a only one function:

- `lib_ops.hpp`:

```
#pragma once
namespace lib {
void lib_operation();
}
```

- `lib_ops.cpp`:

```
#include "lib_ops.hpp"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
namespace lib {
void lib_operation() {
    cout << "LIBRARY TOP LEVEL" << endl;
}
}
```

and, finally, the files `io_ops.hpp` io_ops.cpp`define another function, this time within the namespace`lib::io```:

- `io_ops.hpp`

```
#pragma once
#include "lib_class.hpp"
namespace lib {
namespace io {
void io_operation(dummy& a);
}
}
```

- `io_ops.cpp`

```
#include "io_ops.hpp"

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

namespace lib {
namespace io {
void io_operation(dummy& a) {
    cout << "LIBRARY SUBMODULE" << endl;
    a.asdf();
}
}
}
```

I would like to wrap these files into a Python interface so that I can:

```
import lib
d = lib.dummy(10)
lib.ioop.io_operation(d)
lib.lib_operation()
```

In other words, I would like the organization of the Python wrapper to be:

```
lib.dummy              # class
lib.lib_operation      # function
lib.ioop               # submodule
lib.ioop.io_operation  # function within submodule
```

I've written the following `*.i` files:

- `lib.i`:

```
%module lib
%import ioop.i
%{
#include "lib_ops.hpp"
#include "lib_class.hpp"
%}
%include "lib_ops.hpp"
%include "lib_class.hpp"
```

- `ioop.i`:

```
%module ioop
%{
#include "io_ops.hpp"
using namespace lib;
%}
%include "io_ops.hpp"
```

This compiles without errors with:

```
g++ -c -fPIC io_ops.cpp
g++ -c -fPIC lib_ops.cpp
g++ -c -fPIC lib_class.cpp
swig -c++ -python -py3 lib.i
swig -c++ -python -py3 ioop.i
g++ -fPIC -c lib_wrap.cxx -I /usr/include/python3.6
g++ -fPIC -c ioop_wrap.cxx -I /usr/include/python3.6
g++ -fPIC -shared -o _lib.so lib_wrap.o lib_ops.o lib_class.o
g++ -fPIC -shared -o _ioop.so ioop_wrap.o io_ops.o lib_class.o
```

however, the python script above gives the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py3", line 5, in <module>
    lib.ioop.io_operation(d)
  File "/home/lluis/Desktop/example.i/ioop.py", line 66, in io_operation
    return _ioop.io_operation(a)
TypeError: in method 'io_operation', argument 1 of type 'dummy &'
```

Although I managed to "insert" the namespace `lib::io` into the "main" module `lib` as a submodule `ioop`, it looks as though it didn't know anything about the class `lib::dummy`.

Is it possible to do this? If so, how can I do it?

Thanks to all of you for your time (and sorry for such a lengthy post).

Comment: In ioops.i you'll need to use %import with the lib.i file, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30413268/168175

Comment: @Flexo Thanks, that helps. I had considered this before, but this gives a "weird" thing: I can access _lib_ from within _ioop_. This is a valid Python script: "import lib; d = lib.ioop.lib.dummy(10)". Is this considered correct? If _lib_ was large, would it be efficient to load _lib_ if its submodules also import it?

Comment: I can't confirm right now, but I think that's just normal python import behaviour and they should both refer to the same module, I.e it isn't listed twice, it's loaded once with 2 references.

Comment: @Flexo, you are right again. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19077396/12075306. The answer gives an example on how a module is never imported twice. Would you like to do the honours and write the answer? And, by the way, thanks a lot for answer another question of mine ;) You are a life saver.

Comment: @Flexo, your answer did help, but now I've got other problems in the larger project I'm preparing. It has to do with being able to import a module with "import ioop as io". Using "%module(moduleimport='import ioop as io') ioop" does not help because the code in the .py file generated by SWIG uses the name '_ioop'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Flexo pointed out in one of the comments, the file `ioops.i` needs an `%import`. The correct contents of the file are:

```
%module ioop
%import lib.i
%{
#include "io_ops.hpp"
using namespace lib;
%}
%include "io_ops.hpp"
```